# Approve button on OAuth authorization dialog is invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, api

[image]

There's supposed to be a button there... and while I think of it, wasn't the Reject button supposed to be red?

More specifically, there *is* an Approve button there, just to the left of the Reject button, but it's all white, so it's functionally invisible.

Comment: Simple way to reproduce would be great. :)

Comment: You need API credentials to reproduce, @ShadowWizard. If you follow the API authentication docs, you'll get to this page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that it really helps to actually serve the CSS library you're using if you want the classes to apply correctly.

The fix is building out now. Thanks for the report!